# Vertically & horizontally align text after CSS rotation

Tags: css

So I'm using CSS to rotate some text from horizontal to vertical (90 degrees) like so:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
```

My problem is that this shifts the text way outside of the container div.  Is there a trick to keep it inside the container? Is there some anchor point that I could set? What is a cross browser way to adjust post?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could pull it back in with a few CSS properties...

```
#whatever {
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    right: -10px;
}
```

Alternatively, you could play with the [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform-origin) property:

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform-origin:20% 40%;
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-ms-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Firefox */
-moz-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Firefox */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Opera */
-o-transform-origin:20% 40%; /* Opera */
```

Comment: what if I have resizeble parent element ? how will I be able to achieve it ??

Comment: Thanks, works fine in FF. But is there a way to get it to work in IE8 as well with a workaround?

Comment: FYI... to answer my previous comment above: alignment works in IE8 with the following: do not use "filter: flipv fliph", use "writing-mode: rl-bt;"... with conditional styles it works across IE and FF.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative method, which is more browser compliant and doesn't need information about amount of text beforehand:

```
.disclaimer {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d29cmkej/