# CSS rotate text but keep the vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, rotation

I'm creating a website where I use the rotate and transform functions in CSS3. I have everything under control, but when I rotate my text, the whole text rotates like with its `<p>` block. 
What I want is when rotating my text, keeping the left side of the text in a vertical alignment.

It's hard to explain with words, so I like to refer to this website: [Active Theorie](http://activetheory.net/work/clouds-over-cuba/)

(You can see that they rotate their text like -2 degrees, but keep the vertical alignment of their texts.)

I hope someone here can help me out with this.

Comment: It looks like they use a MASSIVE amount of javascript to generate everything on the fly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600099/vertically-horizontally-align-text-after-css-rotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either css "transform: skew" property 
e.g.

```
.text {
    transform: skew(0,-10deg);
}
```

or if you need perspective view you can use "perspective" and "transform: rotateY"  properties
e.g.

```
.parentDiv : {
    perspective: 500px;
}
.text: {
    transform: rotateY(30deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yjo3aanr/

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for! thanks a lot.