# Vertically align floating div to an unknown sized div

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a `div` of unknown size and another `div` (with CSS rotated text) floating beneath each other.
I am now trying to move the text to the vertical middle, but I don't get it to work.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="unknownSizeDiv"> ... </div>
    <div id="rotatedTextDiv"> ... </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="unknownSizeDiv"> ... </div>
    <div id="rotatedTextDiv"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Or in big:
http://jsfiddle.net/229mvsdb/

It should look like this aftwards:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qKP9jji.png]

I tried working with the solution given here: [Vertically & horizontally align text after CSS rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600099/vertically-horizontally-align-text-after-css-rotation)

But its just for `div`s of known size.

And this one: [How to vertically middle-align floating elements of unknown heights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557897/how-to-vertically-middle-align-floating-elements-of-unknown-heights)

*Should* work for my problem I think, but as you can see in the jsfiddle, **its not**.

Comment: Is js a solution for you? Or pure css?

Comment: it has to be pure css. (but with no compatibility for old browsers)

Comment: That way you are out of luck =(. I wanted to ask you about if float was a requirement. Floats don't obey vertical-align rules. Either you use known div heights, or you have to switch to display: inline-block

Comment: Second comment - if online-block is an option for you, I would be glad to help =)

Comment: Thanks for your great involvement Alexey! :) I know thats not a good reply: but I'm new to the whole CSS thing so I don' know if `display: inline-block;` is also okay. If I can do the same as with `float` right now, yeah: why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is achievalbe](http://jsfiddle.net/gvyo0mry/1/) using pure CSS. Here's what you're going to do with your CSS.

```
     .paragraphWrapper{ position: relative; } /*so that its absolutely positioned children calculate their offset wrt this element*/
     .paragraphWrapper:after{ content: ''; display: table; clear: both; }
     .paragraphWrapper > div{
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
     }
     .paragraph{
        border: 1px dashed #ccc;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        margin: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        width: 415px;
     }
     .paragraphMetaInfo{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 405px;
        /*move them 50% of text's width towards top to get properly centered*/
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
        transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 0) /*as pointed out by Shikkediel*/
     }
```

Comment: So the whole `.paragraphWrapper > div` part isn't needed with your solution, right? http://jsfiddle.net/uxqc5p42/

Comment: No, omitting that rule doesn't have any effect on the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your following rule doesn't have any effect:

```
.paragraphWrapper > div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

because the `<div>` child elements are being `float`ed. Therefore [the computed value of `display` would be `block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).

> **[9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)**
>
> The three properties that affect box generation and layout —
>   `display`, `position`, and `float` — interact as follows:
>
> 3. [...] Otherwise, if 'float' has a value other than 'none', the box is floated and 'display' is set according to the table below. [...]

```html
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                        Specified value                        |   Computed value   |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|   inline, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group,  |                    |
|   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row,          |       block        |
|   table-cell, table-caption, inline-block                     |                    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Actually, there's no real way to align floated elements vertically. But if using `inline-block`s is an option, the following could be a good starting point:

```css
.paragraphWrapper {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.paragraph {
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 415px;
}

.paragraphWrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.paragraphMetaInfo {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(50%);
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraphWrapper">
    <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,</div>
    <div class="paragraphMetaInfo" id="paragraphMetaInfo_0">1. Paragraph
        <br/>64 Words</div>
</div>
<div class="paragraphWrapper">
    <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <div class="paragraphMetaInfo" id="paragraphMetaInfo_1">2. Paragraph
        <br/>184 Words</div></div>
    <div class="paragraphWrapper">
        <div class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <div class="paragraphMetaInfo" id="paragrapheMetaInfo_2">3. Paragraph
            <br/>214 Words</div></div>
```